# PhpStorm parou de reconhecer alguns arquivos .php

Tags: phpstorm

Após eu renomear um arquivo php, o PhpStorm não reconhece mais esse arquivo como um .php. O arquivo fica sem as cores, não dá sugestões, enfim, fica como um arquivo genérico.
A imagem abaixo mostra no caso o status.php. Como faço para ele ser reconhecido como php?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual versão do phpstorm é? veja se esse arquivo está associado com o editor de php, click com o botão direito, veja se tem a opção `open with`

Comment: É a versão 9.0.2. Configurei pra ele ser o padrão pra abrir .php, no windows está normal. Isso é só dentro do phpstorm e aconteceu depois de renomear o aquivo

Comment: Quando eu disse editor associado, quis dizer dentro do phpstorm, tem varios editores, php, javascript etc. seu arquivo parece estar associado com o editor de texto puro ... eu não tenho o phpstorm aqui para testar mas imagino que funcione de forma similar ao eclipse.

Comment: Entendi, realmente não tem a opção **open with***

Comment: Fiz uma busca de ação _Ctrl+Shift+A_ e busquei por _File Types_ e encontrei o arquivo associado a .txt. Obrigado @rray e ao Rodrigo abaixo, pois vcs me encaminham para descobrir isso.

Comment: vc poderia postar uma resposta de como resolveu o problema, fica bom se tiver uns screenshots.

Comment: Postar como uma resposta à minha pergunta?

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o seguinte comando: <kbd>Crtl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> depois procure por File Types (tipos de aqruivos).

Selecionando opção Text, veja se no quadro abaixo em Registered Patterns
o nome do seu arquivo php não consta.

Quando tive esse problema no meu no final da lista constava um
"ExemploArquivoPHP.php", foi dó remover e deu certo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Você renomeou o arquivo com a extensão `.txt`. Basta selecioná-lo, ir em *Refactor > Rename* e renomeá-lo de volta com a extensão `.php`.

Comment: Ele está .php, mesmo indo em rename. A caixa fica Status.php, exatamente assim.

Comment: Mesmo se eu apagar o arquivo e criar novamente falando que é .php, ele volta dessa forma. É como se estivesse gravado na ide que todo Status.php não é php

Comment: Descobri que existe um comando chamado *mark as plain text* quando você clica com o botão direto no arquivo. Tende clicar de novo e selecionar a opção *mark as PHP*.

Comment: Talvez cliquei sem querer aí, mas no status.php nao tem uma opção contrária

Comment: existe essa opção em outro arquivo?

Comment: Existe um arquivo no caminho `.idea/misc.xml` que o PHPStorm gerencia. Nele você irá ver o arquivo dentro de uma lista `<component name="ProjectPlainTextFileTypeManager">`. Tente excluir a linha correspondente ao arquivo dessa lista e reiniciar o PHPStorm.

Comment: Só nos arquivos normais, tipo products.php na imagem

Comment: No arquivo não tem o nó 'ProjectPlainTextFileTypeManager'. Muito estranho